# Should I use the DOM or react redux state to launch/wire up a modal?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

With jquery I would have a modal that I would reference using the DOM id and then inject the template using jQuery etc.

With Reactjs, would it be better for me to do the following:

1. onClick will dispatch an action and pass the parameters
2. my redux reducer will then update the state with those parameters
3. the modal's CSS will update updated based on the state that just changed, and then display the modal window.

Is that the react way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *new and improved* way to do modals is via [Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html)

They have a basic modal example on that page. For posterity, I'll include the example here:

```
// These two containers are siblings in the DOM
const appRoot = document.getElementById('app-root');
const modalRoot = document.getElementById('modal-root');

class Modal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.el = document.createElement('div');
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // The portal element is inserted in the DOM tree after
    // the Modal's children are mounted, meaning that children
    // will be mounted on a detached DOM node. If a child
    // component requires to be attached to the DOM tree
    // immediately when mounted, for example to measure a
    // DOM node, or uses 'autoFocus' in a descendant, add
    // state to Modal and only render the children when Modal
    // is inserted in the DOM tree.
    modalRoot.appendChild(this.el);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    modalRoot.removeChild(this.el);
  }

  render() {
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(
      this.props.children,
      this.el,
    );
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {clicks: 0};
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    // This will fire when the button in Child is clicked,
    // updating Parent's state, even though button
    // is not direct descendant in the DOM.
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      clicks: prevState.clicks + 1
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <p>Number of clicks: {this.state.clicks}</p>
        <p>
          Open up the browser DevTools
          to observe that the button
          is not a child of the div
          with the onClick handler.
        </p>
        <Modal>
          <Child />
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function Child() {
  // The click event on this button will bubble up to parent,
  // because there is no 'onClick' attribute defined
  return (
    <div className="modal">
      <button>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, appRoot);
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically if you're using React you want to stay away from other DOM manipulation libraries and just do all your DOM manipulations in React. The way you have described is how I typically open modals in React. I also use [react-modal](http://reactcommunity.org/react-modal/) to make this a little easier.